# No puedo ver el servidor web de apache de mi laptop desde Internet

Tags: apache2

Al principio si podía acceder a mi servidor web de apache desde Internet por la IP, pero desde hace varios días no logro acceder a mi servidor web de apache desde Internet.

El servidor web está bien, accedo desde mi propia máquina con localhost o la IP que tengo asignada y me da el mensaje de bienvenida de Default Page de apache.

Puedo hacer ping en ambos sentidos entre mi laptop y cualquier otro PC conectado a Internet.

Pongo cualquier puerto diferente a 80 en apache, incluso el 8080 y si puedo ver el servidor web desde Internet, pero no es la idea que tenga que poner la IP más el puerto, en este caso el puerto 8080 o el puerto que sea. http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080

Probé conectar mi laptop en otro servicio de Internet que obviamente tiene otra IP y si puedo ver mi servidor web de apache normalmente por la IP y cualquier servidor conectado a Internet puede verla igualmente.

El detalle está es que tengo IP fija en mi servicio de Internet.

Tengo un servidor **Lubuntu 18.04** y un **apache2 2.4.29** *(Ubuntu)*

*¿Qué puede estar pasando?*

*¿alguna idea que me ayude a salir de este atolladero?*

Comment: Primero que nada tenes que abrir los puertos desde tu router de salida en este caso 8080 y que apunte la ip interna de tu maquina en ese caso Lubuntu 18.4.  podes revisar a  para checkear si los puertos estan abiertos en http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Answer (score 0):

Ciertamente el router debe de redirigir el tráfico de entrada desde internet y que busque el puerto 80 o 8080, a la ip de tu servidor web y al puerto 80 o 8080.

Obviamente el servidor web debe servir la página en uno de esos puertos y todos deben coincidir.

Aquí tienes instrucciones para ver si el servidor está escuchando en ese puerto.
https://ubunlog.com/como-comprobar-los-puertos-en-uso-en-linux/

Si todo eso está bien quizá tu proveedor bloquea ese puerto y no está abierto.

Aquí puedes comprobar desde internet qué puertos se ven abiertos.
http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/#

Ten en cuenta que también pudiera que ser que se vea CERRADO por que se le haya dicho al router que no conteste al ping cuando realmente está ABIERTO.

Si lo ves todo bien configurado desde luego el problema está en el proveedor de internet.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacer la configuración que deseas en el router. Para ello hay que entrar en la pagina de configuración de tu router (cada modelo tiene su forma de acceder, pero normalmente se accede a traves de un navegador tecleando http://IP-DE-TU-ROUTER) y luego busca la opción de redirección de puertos.

Tendras que mapear el puerto externo 80 a la ip de tu portatil, puerto 8080.

Es conveniente que hagas estas pruebas con el firewall del portatil desactivado (ufw disable) para evitar que pueda haber interferencias. Luego lo puedes activar: si dejara de funcionar, ya sabrás que tienes que habilitar el puerto 8080 en el firewall del portatil.